# Are the configuration keys in asp.net core supposed to be case-insensitive?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I made a custom configuration provider for my ASP.NET Web App, where I inherit from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationProvider`, and override the `Load()` method and init the prop `IDictionary<string, string> Data` with a new `Dictionary<string, string>()`.

So I have a appsettings.json config file, containing

```
{
    "Token" : "Token 1"
}
```

And in my custom provider, I override Token with "Token 2"

I had a bug in my code, where I called `configuration["token"]` (lowercase), and I noticed the value from the appsettings was loaded, but not the one from my custom provider.

So it seems that the appsettings configuration is case-insensitive, but my custom provider
isn't.
So is it supposed to be ? I just created a new Dictionary, I'm not sure if it's possible to make it case-insensitive without writing a lot more code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The providers that Microsoft provide from NuGet as part of .NET itself use case insensitive keys ([code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/00ee1c18715723e62484c9bc8a14f517455fc3b3/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/src/ConfigurationProvider.cs#L24)) by default.

Whether or not your custom provider is case sensitive or not is up to you, but I would suggest doing the same and backing the source with a case-insensitive key-value lookup.

If you're using a `Dictionary<K, V>`, then it's as simple as just using the same constructor that takes a comparer and using `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: The documentation on [Implement a custom configuration provider in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider) says this: _Since configuration keys are case-insensitive, the dictionary used to initialize the database is created with the case-insensitive comparer (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)._

It's the only place I found in the documentation where case-insensitivity is mentioned. I'd rather not implement a custom provider with case-sensitive keys since its against the expectation (built-in providers are all case-insensitive).

Comment: Oh, I found another place where case-insensitivity is documented: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/#configuration-keys-and-values) explicitly states that _Configuration keys are case-insensitive. For example, `ConnectionString` and `connectionstring` are treated as equivalent keys._